# Geeting the count of columns by grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an `activities` table which contains information like which `user` performed which `action`. where each user can perform multiple actions.

I want to select from `activities` table the count of each actions performed.

I have written a query like

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
   SELECT MAX(action_id) AS action_id
   FROM activities
   GROUP BY participant_id
   ) T
  GROUP BY action_id
```

It works, but I am not sure if this is the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

This is giving you erroneous datas. You aren't getting *"the count of each actions performed."*, but *the count of each actions that have the highest id of actions per users*

Remove the `participant_id` part and your query can be simplified (and fixed) :

```
SELECT action_id,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM activities
GROUP BY action_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather ambiguous on what you want to accomplish.  The solution appears to be an aggregation *by action_id*.  The following counts both the number of rows and the number of participants:

```
SELECT action_id,
       COUNT(*) as num_actions,
       COUNT(DISTINCT participant_id) as num_participants
FROM activities
GROUP BY action_id;
```

If you wanted the number of actions *per participant*, it would look like:

```
SELECT participant_id,
       COUNT(*) as num_actions
FROM activities
GROUP BY participant_id;
```